# Have you ever succeed in developing high-load web-applications with JSF?

Tags: java, performance, jsp, jsf

I heard a lot about performance problems with jsf (and even asked related question here some time ago).

But today I've heard concrete results of jsf performance tests. From the results where jsp  showed response time 0-100ms jsf application showed 1000-1200ms. Testing of form submission showed 100-200ms for jsp versus ~1500ms for jsf.

I didn't see the code (and I'm not so big expert in jsf to verify that code), but I know that guys spent much time to optimize jsf performance in tested application.

Does it mean that if my web-site should process 100+ requests per second then I should use something else but not jsf?

Comment: could you give a link to that benchmark?

Comment: @Bozho: no, I can't, I don't think that results were documented anywhere.

Comment: I hope I'll have enought time next week to make correspondent benchmark by myself. I'll compare (Spring MVC + JSP) with JSF performance on basic operations. I'll post my results in this thread as soon as I can.

Comment: Nice idea. I would suggest to use Apache JMeter for this: http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/

Comment: @BalusC and @Roman I will be running jmeter "tests" against my current JSF 1.2 project in a week or so, so I might share the results.

Comment: Hi, This is pretty old, but I really hope to know about high availability results for jsf 2, especially after reading Matt Raible's opinions on component based frameworks scalability (and especially high availability). So please share any of your experiences. I am working on an application that is supposed to be used by 100k users

Answer (score 7):

Sun JSF RI 1.0 and 1.1 were indeed performance hogs and it indeed became negatively in the news. However, since JSF RI 1.2 (Mojarra) around early 2006, which was maintained by a new, young and excellent dev team, a lot of performance related enhancements and fixes were done. Also, computers became faster in years. The differences as opposed to "plain JSP" and other frameworks are nowadays very minimal. JSF still needs to get rid of her old "hogging slow" imago.

If one still encounters performance problems nowadays, then it's often just caused by bad code, regardless of the framework used, or ignorance of how HTTP works under the hoods in the complete picture (a lot can already be enhanced with [a few simple things](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/09/webapplication-performance-tips-and.html)).